# Retrieving some values in array

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi
I have an array of random question nos (ids). I have one form with a label for the question, a radiobutton list for their answers and a next button & checkbox to review that question. When I click the next button next(random from array) question appears. I want question id(array) those are checked for review.  How can I do this?
I used code as follows that calculates array (like this:10111) as i gives 1 value for checked & 0 for unchecked rather that this i want array of question ids those are checked :

```
//Code gives array of checked values in terms of 1 & o
            int g;
            if (chkmark.Checked == true)
            {
                g = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                g = 0;
            }
            int[] chkarray = new int[Convert.ToInt32(Session["Counter"]) - 1];
            int[] temp1 = (int[])Session["arrofchk"];
            int k, no;

            if (temp1 == null)
                no = 0;
            else
                no = temp.Length;
            for (k = 0; k < no; k++)
            {
           chkarray[k] = temp1[k];
            }
            chkarray[j] = g;
```

Comment: Any code you would like to show?

Comment: code sample could help understand what you are trying to do

Comment: can't understand anything from your code

Comment: I provided an answer based on his initial question and I'm more lost now after he added the code.  Can you try to explain your problem a little better?  You have an array of 1's and 0's and you want to randomly get one of the "1's"?  If so, it sounds like you need some LINQ-fu

Answer (score 1):

With the information you have given, this is the best I can do.  This will return a random number from your array which I assume to be of ints since it holds numbers (or IDs as you said).

```
        int[] questionIDs = new int[10];
        Random randomIndex = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        int nextQuestion = questionIDs[randomIndex.Next(questionIDs.Length - 1)];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are generating the random questions correctly.

So when you click the next button you can check whether the checkbox for review question is checked or not. If its checked just save the corresponding id of question or save 0 into temp array and save it in session like you done.